# Convert.ToDateTime DD:HH:mm:ss C#/ASP.net GridView RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, date, datetime

The basis of my question is to color a cell in a ASP.net Grid View control.
I have a bound field that is produced from this in SQL

```
 RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(6), SUM([Coaching]) / 86400), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(6), SUM([Coaching]) % 86400 / 3600), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SUM([Coaching]) % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SUM([Coaching]) % 60), 2)
```

It is not great for working with I know but the Project rules that I have says I have to have in a format of `DD:HH:MM:SS` for the display.

All that being said I'm trying to do a row data bound event in C# to color the cell if it is over a certain Minute

```
    protected void TheGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //this is where we will color the columns

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int CoachingIndex = GetColumnIndexByName(e.Row, "Coaching");
        DateTime CoachingValue = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[CoachingIndex].Text);
        string columnValue = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Coaching")).Text;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, columnValue)) > Convert.ToDateTime("00:00:40:00"))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[CoachingIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }            
    }
}
int GetColumnIndexByName(GridViewRow row, string columnName)
{
    int columnIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
            if (((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField.Equals(columnName))
                break;
        columnIndex++; // keep adding 1 while we don't have the correct name
    }
    return columnIndex;
}
```

This conversion if `(Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, columnValue)) > Convert.ToDateTime("00:00:40:00"))` is where the problem lies just trying to figure out how to get this to work in C# so I can do the comparison.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is it `00:00:40:00` days Hours minutes seconds?

Comment: Can you post the error that may help find a solution.

Comment: Sudhakar, it is Days Hours Minutes Seconds yes.

Comment: Kpt.Khaos, the error is SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: i see your comparison fails but i can't seems to figure out what are you trying to compare too.. you are on databound event that point you are trying to bind stuff means nothing is on the grid yet. right?

Comment: AJP, the grid is built after selections are made on the page and based on the selections columns are added or removed. This means that i have to catch it after the fact. Or so I am trying to do that. Can I not do that after the fact ?

Comment: Use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`. You will need to replace the first `:` with `.` for `TimeSpan.Parse` to succeed.

Comment: If you set a break point, does the “columnValue”, have a valid date string?
Also, you might use DateTime.TryParse to get a valid date before doing a comparison. I believe you’ll get a parsing exception if the string value cannot be converted; the TryParse could handle that exception for you.

Comment: Also, like Michael mentioned. It looks like you need a TimeSpan rather than a DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the help I was able to work on it today after all the info provided was able to get it to work.

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        int CoachingIndex = GetColumnIndexByName(e.Row, "Coaching");   
        TimeSpan timeStamp;
        string timeStampString = e.Row.Cells[CoachingIndex].Text; // just change the index of cells to get the correct timestamp field
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(timeStampString, out timeStamp))
        {
            TimeSpan TS = timeStamp;
            int mins = TS.Minutes;
            int hours = TS.Hours;
            int days = TS.Days;
            if (mins > 40 || hours >= 1 || days >= 1)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[CoachingIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                    
            }
        }            
    }
}
int GetColumnIndexByName(GridViewRow row, string columnName)
{
    int columnIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
            if (((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField.Equals(columnName))
                break;
        columnIndex++; // keep adding 1 while we don't have the correct name
    }
    return columnIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a common safe function like that while parsing the date:

```
public DateTime? GetSafeDateTimeValue(object datetimeValue)
        {
            if (datetimeValue == null || datetimeValue == DBNull.Value)
                return null;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!DateTime.TryParse(datetimeValue.ToString(), out tempDateTimeValue))
                        return null;
                    else
                        return tempDateTimeValue;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

**And replace your line with**

```
DateTime? dt = GetSafeDateTimeValue((DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, columnValue)));
if(dt.HasValue)
 if (dt.Value > Convert.ToDateTime("00:00:40:00"))
```

**Second problem you will face that the date time parser must expect the year, instead of parsing the datetime string take datetime instance like below:**

```
DateTime comparedDt = new DateTime(2014, 03, 10, 00, 40, 00);
```